# WebSockets in Chrome and Firefox Disconnecting After One Minute of Inactivity

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have found that WebSockets in Chrome and Firefox disconnect after exactly one minute of inactivity.  Based on stuff I've seen online, I was all set to blame proxies or some server settings or something, but this does not happen in IE or Edge.  It seems like if sockets are disconnected by the server after one minute of inactivity that would apply to IE and Edge just as much as Chrome and Firefox.

Does anyone know why this is?  Is it documented anywhere?  I know a possible way to stop it by pinging, but I'm more interested in why it's happening.  The reason code given on disconnect is 1006, indicating that the browser closed the connection.  No errors are thrown and the onerror event for the socket is not triggered.

This project was built at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/noiseless-helmet where you can see and run everything.  The client page is served here: https://noiseless-helmet.glitch.me/

Here is my client page:

```
<div id="div">
</div>
<script>
  let socket = new WebSocket("wss://noiseless-helmet.glitch.me/");
  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    div.innerHTML += "<br>message " + new Date().toLocaleString() + " " + event.data;
  };
  socket.onopen = function (event) {
    div.innerHTML += "<br>opened " + new Date().toLocaleString();
    socket.send("Hey socket! " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  };
  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    div.innerHTML += "<br>socket closed " + new Date().toLocaleString();
    div.innerHTML += "<br>code: " + event.code;
    div.innerHTML += "<br>reason: " + event.reason;
    div.innerHTML += "<br>clean: " + event.wasClean;
  };
  socket.onerror = function(event) {
    div.innerHTML += "<br>error: " + event.error;
  };
</script>
```

And here is my Node.js server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

let server = require('http').createServer(),
  WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server });

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

let webSockets = [];
wss.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
  webSockets.push(socket);
  webSockets.forEach((w) => { w.send("A new socket connected"); });
  socket.on('close', (code, reason) => {
    console.log('closing socket');
    console.log(code);
    console.log(reason);
    let i = webSockets.indexOf(socket);
    webSockets.splice(i, 1);
  });
});

server.on('request', app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Have you hosted this on a VPS like AWS or Digital Ocean and tried?

Comment: This can happen if you use a VPN (or maybe your internet provider can close the connection, but it's not probable). As for old non-Chromium Edge, it seems to send ping packets automatically.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> It seems like if sockets are disconnected by the server after one minute of inactivity that would apply to IE and Edge just as much as Chrome and Firefox.

Hmmm, no, it doesn't. IE and Edge *might* be implementing a `ping` packet as part of the WebSocket protocol.

[The WebSocket protocol includes support for a protocol level `ping`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-37) that the JavaScript API doesn't expose. It's a bit lower-level than the user level pinging that is often implemented.

This `ping`-`pong` traffic resets the timers in any network intermediaries (proxies, load balancers, etc') - and they all time connections to mark stale connections for closure (for example, the [Heroku setup times connections at 55 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#router)).

Most browsers trust the server to implement the `ping`, which is polite (since servers need to manage their load and their timeout for pinging...

...however it's also slightly frustrating, since browsers have no idea if a connection was abnormally lost and JavaScript doesn't emit an event for the WebSocket protocol `ping`. This is why many JavaScript clients implement a user level ping (i.e., a JSON `{event: "ping", data: {...}}` or another "empty" event message).

Anyway, I just wanted to point out that your assumption was incorrect, this is still a timeout occurring and the difference in browser behavior is probably related to the browsers themselves.

For a few specifics regarding nginx default timeouts (when proxying WebSocket connections) you can read @Hendry's answer.

Comment: Nice answer. But the author *does* suspect the browser... "It seems like if sockets are disconnected by the *server* after one minute of inactivity that would apply to IE and Edge just as much as Chrome and Firefox." and since it *doesn't*, author suspects IE  is doing something special.

Comment: No browser that I know of implements a "ping" event on WebSocket. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I think Edge was sending ping messages under the hood. Obviously, there’s no JavaScript API on any browser that allows a WebSocket protocol ping. It’s generally assumed that this is a server-side controllable ping.

Comment: Not send ping, see ping.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I think all of them respond with a PONG. Again, there’s no JavaScript layer visibility, it’s under the hood. ... if you want to be sure, post a question and tag me, I’ll try to test and post results.

Comment: You answer is implying browser clients can see “ping” sent by server.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I am almost sure they do. At the very least they are PING aware enough to filter the PING (so it doesn’t get forwarded as a message to the JavaScript layer.

Comment: Yeah, they don’t emit an event. That’s why the paragraph is misleading

Answer (score 14):

As much as i understood from researching this, this is caused by websocket timing out over a period of time when no data is sent. This is probably per browser.

You could use pings to resolve this or just reconnect when you need to use the socket again.

It makes sense to not keep sockets open when they are not used from server side as from browser side. For example, Chrome has a limit how many connections can be open, if the limit would be 64 connections and you have open 64 tabs (which is very likely for me as i always have loads of tabs open) and each tab is connected to a server, no more connections could be done (Actually similar thing happened to me once, when i ran out of available sockets in Chrome, funny).

> There is proxy_read_timeout (http://nginx.org/r/proxy_read_timeout) 
>   which as well applies to WebSocket connections. You have to bump 
>   it if your backend do not send anything for a long time. 
>   Alternatively, you may configure your backend to send websocket 
>   ping frames periodically to reset the timeout (and check if the 
>   connection is still alive).

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,236382,236383#msg-236383

> **Web Sockets have an idle timeout of 60 seconds**: if you do not use a heartbeat or similar via ping and pong frames then the socket assumes that the user has closed the page and closes the socket to save resources.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1205863/Websocket-is-closed-after-min

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1070

Comment: the `proxy_read_timeout` option in **nginx** configuration did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Updating the nginx configuration also helped me! Thx

Answer (score 4):

The WebSocket protocol specification defines Ping and Pong frames that can be used for keep-alive, heart-beats, network status probing. **Ping** means client/server is sending an iq to tell the other side server/client that to keep the connection alive and also the other side will send an acknowledgement with **pong** having same payload data.

You can also define a timeout when the  browser stops respond or be considered dead.

read more: http://vunse.blogspot.in/2014/04/websocket-ping-pong.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a clean solution but this is how I implemented websocket in JS to automatically reconnect when disconnected

```
var socket_main
const mainSocketMessageListener = (event) => {
  //retreive the data here
  console.log(event.data)
}

const mainSocketOpenListener = (event) => {
  console.log("Websocket opened")
  //Example of sending message to websocket here
  socket_main.send(JSON.stringify({
    event: "subscribe",
    data: ["all"]
  }))
}

const mainSocketCloseListener = (event) => {
  if (socket_main) {
    console.error('Websocket disconnected.')
  }
  socket_main = new WebSocket('wss://ws.example.com')
  socket_main.addEventListener('open', mainSocketOpenListener)
  socket_main.addEventListener('message', mainSocketMessageListener)
  socket_main.addEventListener('close', mainSocketCloseListener)
}

//connect the first time
mainSocketCloseListener()
```

Comment: How do you deal with stack overflow exceptions when calling it recursive like this?

Comment: mainSocketCloseListener shouldn't open the websocket directly. it should create a timeout to a function that opens the socket.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to policy changes on chrome and other browsers.

Please see discussions at

- "Chrome terminates WebSocket connection": https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4536
- "How to detect when browser throttles timers and websockets disconnection": [How to detect when browser throttles timers and websockets disconnection after a user leaves a tab or turns off the screen? (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758141/how-to-detect-when-browser-throttles-timers-and-websockets-disconnection-after-a)