# node js socket.io disconnect after idle time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using `socket.io` module in `nodejs`. I am working on an app that uses `socket.io` (`node.js`) for realtime chat messages to all the logged in clients. Many of my users are experiencing disconnections from the `socket.io` server. The normal use case for a client is to keep the web app open the entire working day. Most of the time on the app in a work day time is spent idle, but the app is still open - until the `socket.io` connection is lost and then the app kicks them out.

Is there any way I can make the connection more reliable so users are not constantly losing their connection to the `socket.io`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebSockets in Chrome and Firefox Disconnecting After One Minute of Inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408031/websockets-in-chrome-and-firefox-disconnecting-after-one-minute-of-inactivity)

Comment: @Mehdi No, this is not relevant  to my question.